# Probability - Events

Tags: probability

Two events A and B, are such that P(A) = 0.5, P(B) = 0.8 and P(AUB) = 0.9. Determine:

(i) P(A intersect B)

(ii) P(A|B)

(iii) State, giving reasons, whether or not A and B are independent events.

I attempted (i) = P(A) * P(B) = 0.5 * 0.8 = 0.4

(ii) = P(A intersect B) / P(B) = 0.4 / 0.8 = 0.5

Are these correct?

I am not sure how to answer (iii)

Comment: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$ is true **if and only if** $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  If it is unknown whether or not they are, then you simply may **not** use this.  Instead, use inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Yes thank you, I have made the corrections to the question. I don't understand what you mean by inclusion-exclusion

Comment: For future reference, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) has information on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ on this site so you can use proper notation and symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ is **always true**.  This is a specific case of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  Rearranged, we have $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$

On the other hand $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$ is true **if and only if** $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  That is to say, if $A$ and $B$ are *not* independent, then $P(A\cap B)$ is *not equal* to $P(A)\cdot P(B)$ and similarly if $P(A\cap B)$ is not equal to $P(A)\cdot P(B)$ then $A$ and $B$ are not independent.  If you do not know if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then you may *not* split it apart with multiplication like this.

You *may* however split it apart with multiplication as $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B\mid A)$ or as $P(A\cap B)=P(B)\cdot P(A\mid B)$, as per the definition of conditional probability.

---

Since we do not know in our problem if $A$ and $B$ are independent, we must use other ways of calculating the probability of their intersection, which in this problem would mean specifically using the identity mentioned in my first line.

Comment: Okay, so how do I determine if the events are independent or dependent?

Comment: @Mic.A again, $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$ is true if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent.  First calculate $P(A\cap B)$ using correct and guaranteed methods.  Then calculate $P(A)\cdot P(B)$ and compare the values.  If $P(A\cap B)$ happens to equal $P(A)\cdot P(B)$ then that means they are independent.  If $P(A\cap B)$ happens to *not* equal $P(A)\cdot P(B)$ then that means they are *not* independent.

Comment: Both workings = 0.4, therefore they are independent